# What is the difference between these two queries? Why different results?

Tags: mysql, join, count, subquery

**This** - gives incorrect values for `total_classes`

```
SELECT IFNULL(count(wc.id_wc),0) AS total_classes

FROM `all_tag_relations` AS a
    LEFT JOIN (tags AS t, WebClasses as wc) 
    ON ( a.id_tag = t.id_tag AND a.id_tutor = wc.id_author )
GROUP BY a.id_tutor
```

**But this one** - with a subquery gives correct values -

```
SELECT (SELECT IFNULL(count(wc.id_wc),0) FROM WebClasses as wc WHERE wc.id_author = a.id_tutor) AS total_classes


FROM `all_tag_relations` AS a
     LEFT JOIN (tags AS t) ON ( a.id_tag = t.id_tag) 
group by a.id_tutor
```

**Solution**
The solution is to join the other tables with the actual Tutors table with All_Tag_relations like this

```
...FROM Tutors as td on join All_Tag_Relations as a on td.id_tutor=a.id_tutor LEFT JOIN ...
```

Comment: Are you asking why switching left table to right names a difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both your queries are very strange and it is not clear what you are trying to do. Maybe you should show your tables and ask for a query that retrieves the data you want.

The difference between those queries is mainly that the second one gives you the total number of WebClasses and the second gives you the number ob WebClasses times the number of authors/tutors times the number of tags, given that they are disjoint and there are all 1:n relations between tags, WebClasses and all_tag_relations.

Comment: Yes I understood there is some multiplication happening in the first case. I want am trying to get the total number of classes by an author in the `total_classes` column. What change is needed in the first query to produce the same output as the second?

Comment: you are correct, there is 1:n relation between tutors and tag_relations. In the all_tag_relations table, there are multiple records for every tutor and hence the multiplication.

Comment: Well, number of classes per author is `SELECT id_author,COUNT(*) FROM WebClasses GROUP BY id_author`. How do the tags come in?

Comment: `All_tag_relations` table holds tags for searching tutors, classes. In the above query, the joining with `All_tag_relations` table was for search purpose.